# cakePHP router annoying me with pagination system

Tags: cakephp, pagination, router

When i enter address: http://www.yourdomain.com/2 (without page:2)

It give you Missing View: (error)

```
Missing View

Error: The view for PagesController::display() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: /Users/username/Sites/mycakeapp/views/pages/2.ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create /views/errors/missing_view.ctp
```

In router config: (routes.php in config)

```
$chk = array('page' => '[0-9]');

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

Router::connect('/:page/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'), array(
            'page' => $chk['page'], 'pass' => array('page')
        ));
```

In pages_controller.php:

```
function display($on_page=1) {
$this->paginate = array(
'limit' => $this->Cookie->read('pagelimit'),
'page' => $on_page,
'order' => array(
'data.dateadded' => 'asc'
));
$data = $this->paginate('data');
$this->set('data', $data);

$this->render(implode('/', $path));
$this->set('title_for_layout', null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem solved. the answer is:

add in controller page:

```
$this->render('/pages/home');
```

no need to add Router::connectNamed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all named parameters to the routes config manually:

```
Router::connectNamed(array('page'[, ...]);
```

Comment: I tried `Router::connectNamed(array('page');` and `Router::connectNamed(array('default' => true));` still not work... :(

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message states, you need to have a file called 2.ctp in your pages folder.

> Confirm you have created the file:
>   /Users/username/Sites/mycakeapp/views/pages/2.ctp

The display method in the pages_controller is generally used to display static pages. A file named with the param you send, in your case 2, followed by '.ctp' must exist in the view/pages folder, this is what the error message tells you.

If you where expecting something else, you are not doing it right.